# how to pass stored procedure to servlet and get the data from database using java

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets, stored-procedures

In my application i am inserting the data into database by reading open office spread sheet and i need to get that inserted data by passing stored procedure to my servlet below is the complete servlet code that i tried to retrieve the data but it not working.Can anyone help me out as i am new to this

My stored procedure parameters

```
Procedure Name- Users
Procedure parameters-@fromdate,@todate,@users
```

Servlet code-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
processRequest(request, response);
try
{
SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
Connection conn=null;
ds.setUser("");
ds.setPassword("");
ds.setServerName("");
ds.setDatabaseName(""); 
conn = ds.getConnection(); 
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("Connected!");
//getting the from date ,to date and selected users into string parameters  
String users[] = request.getParameterValues("comments") ;
String FromDate = request.getParameter("pickedDate");
String ToDate = request.getParameter("pickedDate1");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");
writer.println("<h4>You are selected :</h4>");
for(String selecteduser :users)
{
writer.println("<br><font color=black>"+selecteduser+"</font>");
}
ArrayList al = null;
ArrayList pid_list = new ArrayList();

//stored procedure
String query = ""dbo.users", "@fromdate", FromDate , "@Todate", ToDate , "@Users",users[]";



writer.close();
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
exception.printStackTrace(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Sample and check

```
myStoredProcedureCall = 
    sybConn.prepareCall("{call my_stored_procedure (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?)}");
    myStoredProcedureCall.setString(1, "ONE");
    myStoredProcedureCall.setString(2, "TWO");
    myStoredProcedureCall.setString(9, "NINE");
    ResultSet paramResults = myStoredProcedureCall.executeQuery();
```

Comment: i had tried the same  but its not working could you please show it by doing it for my code as i had provided you procedure name and parameters